# find if a backslash exists in a string Go

Tags: regex, go, telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin

I have a string like this:

`id=PS\\ Old\\ Gen`

and I would to build a regex to find out if it contains a backslash; one after the other. So in this case, the regex should find 2 occurances as there are 2 `\\`.

I tried building up the query but couldn't figure out the right way.

i need the regex that's compatiable with Go.

Comment: Any reason that it must be a regexp? Why not just `strings.Count`?

Comment: What are you planning to do? Just detect or also change the string?

Comment: I need to use the regex in a config file. Just detecting. @Dominic

Comment: So you don't need to know how many there are or where they are? Your config file could also just contain a string it doesn't have to be regex does it? Seems better suited to a simple strings function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **strings.Count(myString, `\`)**

with literal example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    myString := `id=PS\\Old\\Gen`
    a := `\`
    i := strings.Count(myString, a)
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

result = 4

without literal

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    myString := "id=PS\\Old\\Gen"
    a := `\`
    i := strings.Count(myString, a)
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

Result=2

if you just need contain use

```
myString := "id=PS\\ Old\\ Gen"
a:=`\`
i := strings.Contains(myString, a)
fmt.Println(i)
```

Result=true

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't need to know the position or occurence of `\\` so in that cause I'd suggest going as simple as possible:

```
import "strings"

...

fmt.Println(strings.Contains("id=PS\\ Old\\ Gen", "\\")) // true
```

So you can just store `"\\"` in your config.

Comment: I have tried that but it complains. It's printing out this: `regexp: Compile(`\`): error parsing regexp: trailing backslash at end of expression: `` `  See this for context: https://community.influxdata.com/t/telegraf-measurement-values-and-strings/6891

Comment: @kjvf are you using `"` or ` (backtick)?

Comment: I am using `"`. I think it looks like a bcktick because of my formatting